# Commerce.js docs say field is optional. Why am I getting an error due to required field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, e-commerce

I am building an e-commerce site with reactjs and commerce.js. Currently I'm testing the checkout process using Stripe. The [commerce.js docs](https://commercejs.com/docs/api/#capture-order) describe the `capture()` method and specifically state that the billing information is optional. It says nothing about a `customer.id` being necessary to bypass billing info. Yet I get this error when I call `commerce.checkout.capture(tokenId, orderData);` without inserting billing info into `orderData`:

```
 Validation/missing fields
billing.country: The Billing country field is required when customer.id is not present.
```

Here is the shape of my `orderData` with no billing info. Note that I get the above error for all missing billing fields. Just trying to shorten the question. If I add `orderData.billing` and duplicate the shipping section, the checkout works fine. Would like to avoid this if possible though. Anyone know why I'm getting this error?

```
const orderData = {
        line_items: checkout_token.line_items,
        customer: {
          firstname: firstname,
          lastname: lastname,
          email: email,
        },
        shipping: {
          name: name_s,
          street: street_s,
          town_city: city_s,
          county_state: state_s,
          postal_zip_code: zip_code_s,
          country: country_s,
        },
        fulfillment: {
          shipping_method: shipping_option.id,
        },
        payment: {
          gateway: "stripe",
          stripe: {
            payment_method_id: paymentMethod.id,
          },
        },
      };
```

Comment: Perhaps other members of this community have suggestions but it sounds like you may need to check in with the Commerce.js support team. The Commerce.js API reference clearly lists `billing` parameters as optional but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @LauraT I think you are correct. Just sent a message to support